# If I am boarding at a regular Greyhound bus stop and not at a station, how will my bags be checked?

Tags: greyhound

If I am boarding at a regular bus stop and not at a station how will my bags be checked?

I will board at a regular bus stop and there will be no place to check in. I’m assuming that the bus driver will check my bags, but I’m not quite sure how that works.

Comment: In my experience, the driver steps out of the bus, checks tickets, and either stows checked bags under the bus, or indicates where in the luggage storage you should place your large bag(s).  Not posting as an answer as I'm not aware of policy or regional variation, but there should be no trouble catching a bus at a location other than a full-service bus station.

Comment: I've never seen a bus terminal that handles baggage loading differently from a curbside stop

Answer (score 4):

I boarded Greyhound at a stop (not a terminal) about 18 months ago and had the exact experience user4556274 described in her comment:

The driver got off the bus and opened the luggage compartment doors. People started chucking their bags under there while he checked tickets for all the passengers. Once a person's ticket was checked (s)he was allowed to board.

This happened at every one of the 6,723 stops on the 12 day journey that should have taken about 3 hours. 
*slight exaggeration - not a fan of bus travel. :(*

The trip ended at a terminal which I returned to 10 days later in order to make the journey back home. It was the *exact same process*, just at a terminal instead of a "stop". There was no baggage check in process like there is at an airport, just the same curbside process with the exception of there being multiple "curbsides" all one right next to the other.

Comment: Heck, it's possible that one or more people on the bus were armed, since I live in a state where concealed carry is still legal. Though I was traveling to one where it's not (yet gun violence is still plentiful), so there _could_ have been issues at the destination end.